# Sonar coverage exclude on Test case coverage level

Tags: sonarqube

We have two different test case coverages, which are Unit Test coverage and Integration Test Coverage, now we want to exclude the code coverage for  few set of classes in Unit Test report and few are in Integration report.

If we use sonar.coverage.exclusion globally in pom.xml that applies to both the reports, so wondering if there is a way to declare it in coverage report level.

```
<sonar.exclusions>org/binarytherapy/generated/**/*, **/GuiceBindComposer.java</sonar.exclusions>
```